# Customize communication of an Exception message to user without using "echo" in catch block?

Tags: php, exception, user-experience

There are many questions that address whether to use exceptions as user messages, and it seems that there are solid adherents to both the yes and no factions and I don't want this question to add to that body of work.  [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133335/handling-errors-in-php-when-using-mvc) is just one example from stackexchange.

I'm new to PHP OOP and I've got a validate method that returns TRUE/FALSE in a class, but when false, I'd like to get the failed validation message back to the user without javascript and display that message with in the page with some css formatting (not at the top etc).

If there is some biblical reason  the method should not generate the user message/text -I'm ok with that - I just want to understand why and a good alternative if possible.

I'm likely to extend the Exception Class for a custom message that doesn't show more serious level errors - so that may or may not be part of a solution, but still doesn't address the user output question.

I'm going to also admit that this may just be a case of trying to shove 10lbs into a 1lb sack. Here's the essence:

```
class MyClass {
function validate_name($newname){
    try {    

     //some code to validate that test for a normal failure conddition

     throw new Exception('a user friendly message')

     }
     catch (Exception $e) { // Report the error!

        echo '<p class=0"error">An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>';
            }//end catch

      }//end validate_name
    }//end Class
```

Then in the page, it's:

```
$obj =  new MyClass();

if (isset($_POST['item'])) {

    $obj->set_new_cat($_POST['item1'],$_POST['item2']);


}//end if isset post 




<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    Name: <br/><input name="item1" type="text" />
    Description (optional): 
    <input name="item2" type="text" />
    <br/>
<?php ???how to display error messages here???>

     <button id="submit" type="submit" name="action" >Add Category</button>
</form>
```

In a prior procedural variation I used an $errors array on the page with the message pulled from the array, but with the method in a class, I'm not certain how to get the return value or a message since the "echo $e->getMessage" won't output as I'd like.

Feeling like I'm missing something simple here,  but I'm a NOOB to this...

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your exception handler so that you are throwing the exception in the event that you can't resolve it.

```
class MyClass {
    function validate_name($newname){
        try {    
            //some code to validate that test for a normal failure conddition
            throw new Exception('a user friendly message');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) { // Report the error!
            throw new Exception('<p class="error">An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>');
        }//end catch    
    }
}
```

Then when you output.

```
$obj =  new MyClass();
$error = "";
if (isset($_POST['item'])) {
    try{
        // assuming this calls validate_name at some point
        $obj->set_new_cat($_POST['item1'],$_POST['item2']);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }

}//end if isset post 

?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    Name: <br/><input name="item1" type="text" />
    Description (optional): 
    <input name="item2" type="text" />
    <br/>
    <?= $error ?>
    <button id="submit" type="submit" name="action" >Add Category</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - and I thought this would work - but in practice - Xdebug reports the exceptions, but $error remains as initialized regardless of Exception generated (using var_dump on $error). I checked code - are you certain this functions as described?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: if the line `$obj->set_new_cat` (which I assume is calling validate_name) is emitting the Exception then $error will be set to the  `'<p class="error">An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage() . '</p>'` unless you are also catching in the set_new_cat method

Comment: Yes, validate_name(), is called as part of the set_new_cat() method. I guess I could call validate_name() separately on the page, but I was trying to leave as much as possible in the class since this code will be repeated often.  Is there a technique that might accomplish this within the class/exception handling?